# Selecting data from a period of full months based on the current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, timestamp

I recently got the task to write a reporting tool to get several data historically.
But I came to a point where I'm stuck. I can't get my data from full months in the past.

Story:
The user gets a field where he can type how long he wants to get the history (of passed months) for example: *I want the data of the last 3 months*. He types his value, sends the data and (should) get an output like this (because we have September right now):

```
X data in August,
Y data in July,
Z data in June.
```

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (publish_up between date_sub(NOW(), 
INTERVAL ".$history." MONTH)
AND date_sub(now(), INTERVAL " . -- $history . " MONTH))
AND created_by = '$editorID' AND state = 1 AND sectionid in (1,2,3)";
```

But with this, obviously I always get the data from NOW - 1 month. So the data I'll show the user is wrong, because it starts somewhere in the middle of a month and ends somewhere in the middle of another month. I want the period to begin at the first day of month and to end with the last day of month.

My first idea was, that I could subtract the amount of days that have already passed in the current month from the current date to get the first day of the last month, but I don't know how to do that. Also I don't know how to get the name of that month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate an arbitrary date based on the current date using PHP functions [mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) and [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

So instead of using awkward, unreadable SQL functions I'd rather calculate the desired time period in PHP directly:

```
$period_end = mktime(0,0,0, date('n'), 1, date('Y')); // first of current month, time 00:00:00
$period_begin = strtotime('-3 months', $period_end);
```

You could then embed these in your SQL query as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE publish_up BETWEEN '" .
         date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $period_begin) ."' AND '" .
         date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $period_end) ."' AND " 
         "created_by = '$editorID' AND state = 1 AND sectionid in (1,2,3)";
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. First of all thanks for your idea! I will try it. Since I need several single outputs, I'll try to use some variable instead of -3 month and increase it in every run. Thanks so far I'll answer after trying

Comment: I think IF I somehow change the variables
`$period_end` to the last of the previous month and `$period_begin` to the first of the previous month with an variable I can increment till I match the users input and go through my for-loop you solved my problem :)

Comment: That's great. I'd be happy if you'd accept my answer then.

Comment: Sure sorry forgot it yesterday :) Didn't manage to get the last of a month :( looks like I need some practise with the `mktime` function

Comment: Look at the format character `'t'` in the docs for the date-function. It gives the number of days in a given month. So the last day of the current month would be: `mktime(0,0,0, date('n'), date('t'), date('Y'))`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the end of the previous month:

```
DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

For Month Name see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the late reaction. To complete your code and have it for multiple uses I changed it to `SELECT DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL ".$month." MONTH, '%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Now I only need the same for the first of the previous month and I got my "between". Thanks so far!

Comment: What about SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL ".$month."+1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table 
WHERE  create_by = '$editorID' AND 
       state = 1 AND 
       sectionid in (1,2,3) AND
       published_up > DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL ".$history." MONTH
```

Comment: This would include all records from the current month, which OP doesn't want.

Answer (score 0):

Use EXTRACT YEAR_MONTH to easily see if the dates lie in the months desired.

```
"SELECT MONTHNAME(publish_up) as month, SUM(some_column), ... 
 FROM mytable 
 WHERE extract(year_month from publish_up) BETWEEN
       extract(year_month from (now() - INTERVAL ".$history." MONTH)) AND
       extract(year_month from now())
 AND created_by = '".$editorID."' AND state = 1 AND sectionid in (1,2,3)
 GROUP BY MONTHNAME(publish_up)";
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I tried your code but I always get syntax errors in my database. I think maybe because the `from (now() - INTERVAL` is no tablerow? But thanks so far for the answer

Comment: It's `"now() - INTERVAL ".$history." MONTH"` which should translate to `now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH` when $history is 1. What error do you get exactly? What does your SQL string actually look like after the concatenation with $history and $editorID?

Comment: I tried the code directly in my SQL database without php in front.
`SELECT MONTHNAME(publish_up) as month, sum(id, publish_up)
 FROM jos_content
 WHERE extract(year_month from publish_up) BETWEEN
       extract(year_month from (now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND
       extract(year_month from now())
 AND created_by = 254268 AND state = 1 AND sectionid in (1,2,3)
 GROUP BY MONTHNAME(publish_up)`

And I'll get #1064 syntax error in line 1

Comment: The error is probably `sum(id, publish_up)`. What is this supposed to mean? SUM takes one parameter, and even if you called SUM(id) or SUM(publish_up); why would you want to sum up ids or dates? That makes no sense. To find errors it is easier btw to put in line breaks. As long as all is in one line and you get a syntax error in line 1, that doesn't say much. Make this 10 lines or so and get a syntax error in line 3 and you know much more.